# Python: mutiplying a boolean array, documentation

Tags: python, boolean, documentation

Where can I find documentation on the code below? Why does multiplying an array by 2, inserts another False into the array?

```
print( [False] * 2 )

output: [False, False]
```

Comment: That is not an array, it is a `list`

Comment: To answer your question as to where you can find the documentation that describes this behaviour please look at [this](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) and look at the 4th entry in the table in section 5.6 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doubled the list. Basically multiplying the number of references inside the list. That is the expected behavior.

```
print(['a', 'b', 'c'] * 3)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: In other words, it basically concatenates itself **X** amount of times

Comment: Documentation https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations

Answer (score 0):

For multiplying the numbers inside a `list` you need to `iterate` through it.
The way you are multiplying gives the output that you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a number of `operator` methods - the multiplication method is called `__mul__` ([https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/operator.html#operator.**mul**](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/operator.html#operator.__mul__)) Any class/module can define its own `__mul__` method, which will be run when it is multiplied (which is what happens when you use `*`)

If you look at a list you can see it has `__mul__` defined:

```
 ["a", "b"].__mul__
 <method-wrapper '__mul__' of list object at 0x7efc163fe9d0>
```

You can call this method with a number:

```
["a", "b"].__mul__(2)
["a", "b", "a", "b"]
```

Comment: Yep - typo - fixed it!